# Number of decimal digits in Oracle SQL Developer query result sheet

Tags: oracle, numbers, decimal, oracle-sqldeveloper

The Date format can be customized in Oracle SQL Developer, how Decimal format can be specified?  By that I mean number of decimal digits.

In Tools>Preferences>Database>NLS we only have decimal separator, nothing else.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option in Preferences to my knowledge. You can use [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#g195443) function to display the decimal digits.

An example:

Try this in HR schema:

```
select to_char(salary,'999999.000'), employee_id from employees;
```

Comment: Thank you @vijayaragavan anyway, however our ideal approach was not to use sql.